# Get return quote price

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have a quote model that holds details for a quotation and we generate a price based on the from and to location. But it gets messy when you want a return price. Here's the code:

```
# Quote model
class Quotation(models.Model):
    from = models.CharField()
    from_place_id = models.TextField()  # Google place ID
    to = models.CharField()
    to_place_id = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    is_return = models.BooleanField()

def get_price(quote):
    // do stuff with quote and return the quote object

def auto_price(quote):
    quote = get_price(quote)
    return_quote = None

    if quote.is_return:
        return_quote = deepcopy(quote)
        return_quote.from = quote.to
        return_quote.from_place_id = quote.to_place_id
        return_quote.to= quote.from 
        return_quote.to_place_id= quote.from_place_id
        return_quote = get_price(quote)
```

I can manually add the values of return_quote in DjangoRest on create() but how do I access this later? There's no return_quote on the original model. Should I make return_quote a JSONField on the model? That will further make things complicated.

Comment: can you post your model? What you tried and what your problem?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: You can try add attribute inside model `Quotation`. But True logic is `return_quote.from_place_id = quote.to_place_id` and `return_quote.to_place_id= quote.from_place_id` ? And what make it messy?